# Are 2 OpenShift pods replicas deployed on two different nodes (when #nodes > 2)?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Assume I have a cluster with 2 nodes and a POD with 2 replicas. Can I have the guarantee that my 2 replicas are deployed in 2 differents nodes. So that when a node is down, the application keeps running. By default does the scheduler work on best effort mode to assign  the 2 replicas in distinct nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Pod AntiAffinity

Pod anti-affinity can also to repel the pod from each other. so no two pods can be scheduled on same node.

Use following configurations.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - nginx
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
```

This will use the anti-affinity feature so if you are having more than 2 nodes the there will be guarantee that no two pod will be scheduled on same node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kind: DeamonSet` . Here is a link to Kubernetes [DeamonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) documentation.

> A *DaemonSet* ensures that all (or some) Nodes run a copy of a Pod. As nodes are added to the cluster, Pods are added to them. As nodes are removed from the cluster, those Pods are garbage collected. Deleting a DaemonSet will clean up the Pods it created.

Here is a link to documentation about [DeamonSets in OpenShift](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/dev_guide/daemonsets.html)
Example might look like the following:

> This is available on Openshift >= 3.2 version of openshift This use case is to run a specific docker container (veermuchandi/welcome) on all nodes (or a set nodes with specific label
>
> Enable HostPorts expose on Openshift
>
> $ oc edit scc restricted  #as system:admin user
>
> change allowHostPorts: true   and save

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: welcome
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: welcome
      labels:
        daemon: welcome
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: c
        image: veermuchandi/welcome
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          hostPort: 8080
          name: serverport
```

> $ oc create -f myDaemonset.yaml  #with system:admin user

Source available [here](https://github.com/debianmaster/Notes/wiki/DaemonSets-(Run-a-container-on-all-nodes)---on-OpenShift)

Answer (score 0):

Daemonset is not a good option. It will schedule one pod on every node. In future if you scale your cluster and then pods get scaled as many as nodes. Instead Use pod affinity to schedule no more than one pod on any node